# NHibernate + threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, nhibernate

I have nearly such code:

```
public class WCFService
{
    public OperationResult Create(...)
    {
        List<SomeClass> classList = new List<SomeClass>();//Items are got from db using       NHibernate
        ...
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate () { 
            foreach ( item in classList)
            {
                Method(item);
            }
        }
    ...
    return new OperationResult();
    }

    public void Method ( List<SomeClass> list) //doesn't use NHibernate Session
    {
    Conslole.Writeline(list.ToString());
    }

}

void main()
{
    WCFService service = new WCFService();
    service.Create(...);
}
```

After execution in console output there are only part of List. I think Method can't get access to elements of list. When debugging there is such message instead of variable value : "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation". Or LazyInitialization Exception "Could not initialize proxy - no Session". Is problem in NHibernate session or something else? And how can I solve it?
Method is in separate thread because it takes too much time, and result of creation need to be returned as fast as possible.

Comment: it would definitly help to see the db access code. but my guess is the session is not available in `Method` anymore. best choice would be to eager fetch all data you need in `Create` and detache (Evict) the objects from the session.

Comment: Even better would be to have a session in that new thread and load objects there.

Comment: Firo : I've tried to detache objects,that i use as arguments of Method, from session, but looks like it doesn't help.  Ladislav Mrnka : I think it's not best way,because it will lead to code duplication and adding several thousand calls to db, that were already done. I think it can help, but it will be better to find better solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the LazyInitialization exception because the method is trying to access a property which is not initialized. By default NH associations are lazy loaded, so upon access to the property, NH tries to load the data from the session, which of course by that time is long gone and disposed of.

A few options:

1. Eager load the associations in your mapping with 'lazy=false'
2. Eager load the associations in your query with 'FetchMode=join'
3. Manually do the loading. After you get your entities,  access the properties to ensure they are loaded (or use NHibernateUtil.Initialize() on the associations).
4. Do something like this http://trentacular.com/2009/08/how-to-use-nhibernate-lazy-initializing-proxies-with-web-services-or-wcf/

Comment: It looks like changing FetchMode in query really helped. Thanks a lot.